# Interactive plot from an IPython console

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter, ipywidgets

I am trying to display an interactive figure containing containing ipywidgets and a plotly figure, which is redrawn every time the widgets are changed. Doing this within a Jupyter notebook is no problem but I am trying to do this from an IPython console. I am aware that the IPython console cannot display the figure. My idea is to

1. start a jupyter server
2. transfer the figure object
3. execute the figure

Below are two python files (helper.py and main.py), which can be put in the same directory. The main.py file is intented for execution.

(helper.py):

```
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


class Dummy():

    def __init__(self):
        self.range_1 = range(10)
        self.range_2 = range(20)

    def display(self):
        dropdown_1 = widgets.Dropdown(
            options=self.range_1,
            description='Start Offset:',
            value=0
        )

        dropdown_2 = widgets.Dropdown(
            options=self.range_2,
            description='End Offset:',
            value=0
        )

        output = widgets.Output()

        def update_figure(change):
            with output:
                clear_output(wait=True)
                fig = px.line(pd.DataFrame([dropdown_1.value * dropdown_2.value]))
                fig.show(renderer='notebook')

        dropdown_1.observe(update_figure)
        dropdown_2.observe(update_figure)

        fig = widgets.VBox([dropdown_1, dropdown_2, output])
        display(fig)
```

(main.py)

```
import os
import sys

import pickle
import nbformat
from nbclient import NotebookClient
import jupytext

sys.path.insert(1, os.getcwd())
import helper


obj = helper.Dummy()
pickled = pickle.dumps(obj)

nb = jupytext.reads(f"import pickle; obj = pickle.loads({pickled}); obj.display()")
# nb = nbformat.reads(nb, as_version=4)
client = NotebookClient(nb, timeout=600, store_widget_state=True)
client.execute()
nbformat.write(nb, 'executed_notebook.ipynb')
os.system("jupyter notebook executed_notebook.ipynb")
```

Allthough the above approach works, it seems to be cumbersome. I did not find any better method or a method at all searching stackoverflow etc. Does anybody have a better, more straightforward idea (except using jupyter directly)?

Answer (score 0):

The more natural way for plotly figures to be combined with dropdowns, buttons, etc. is the use of dash.